# append function does not highlight under def function

Tags: python

defining a function that adds the elements of the 2nd list to the 1st one, the append function does not highlight
it returns a "none" output
i apologize if this is a very simple question but i'm a beginner

```
b = ["b"]
a = ["a"]
def addem(x, y):
    for z in x:
        y.append(z)
print(addem(a, b))
```

it returns "None"

Comment: All python functions return a single object. If you don't have an explicit `return`, python returns `None`. Is that what you mean by "highlight"?

Comment: the function append doesn't show in a different color

Comment: and it doesn't work either

Comment: Functions don't have color by themselves. Is this a tool you are using? Maybe vscode or jupyter notebook? As for not working, it prints "None". What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Why should it show in a specific color (to indicate what)? list.append modifies the respective list and does not return anything (therefor returns None)

Comment: It would be more common to call the function, ignore its return value, and then `print(b)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function doesn't return anything. It should be:

```
b = ["b"]
a = ["a"]

def addem(x, y):
    for z in x:
        y.append(z)
    return y

print(addem(a, b))
```